# Setting Only One Namespace in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I'm having some issues with namespaces in LINQ. So going off of [MSDN's Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) we can do the following to add namespaces to an XML document with LINQ:

```
// Create an XML tree in a namespace.
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Root",
    new XElement(aw + "Child", "child content")
);
Console.WriteLine(root);
```

Which will give you the XML:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">
  <Child>child content</Child>
</Root>
```

But what I want to do is this:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Roots");
XElement child = new XElement("Child", "child content");
root.Add(child);

Console.WriteLine(root);
```

But this gives me the following xml:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">
    <Child xmlns="">child content</Child>
</Root>
```

The problem is I don't want the `xmlns=""` in my child elements **(EDIT: I don't want any namespaces in my child elements)**, I want it to look just like the first way produces it. I am building a fairly large XML file so I can't add all the elements in the same declaration and need to be able to use the `Add` and `SetAttributeValue` methods of multiple `XElements` still having an `xmlns` on the first element. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is fundamental to the XML information set.  The effect of the `xmlns` declaration is scoped to all child content; since you did not specify a namespace for the child element, the standard behavior is to place it in the unnamed namespace.  In order to nest an element in an unnamed namespace inside of one that declares a default namespace, the `xmlns=''` declaration is required to reset the default namespace to unnamed.

To summarize, based on your edit:

- If you don't want any *namespaces* in your child elements, then an **explicit `xmlns=''` is required** by the [XML Namespaces specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) in order to override the namespace declared in the document element.
- If you don't want any *namespace declarations* (*i.e.* `xmlns=''` stuff) in your child elements, you need to make sure the **same namespace is added to the names of all of them** in code.

There is no way I know of to make an `XElement` automatically inherit the namespace of its parent.  After you are done building the DOM, though, you can always postprocess it to set one namespace everywhere with something similar to this:

```
foreach(var element in doc.Descendants())
    element.Name = aw + element.Name.LocalName;
```

I don't believe doing this is advisable for anything other than throwaway code, though, since it will likely have untoward effects on maintainability.  A number of XML documents I've had to deal with mix namespaces, and "smashing" namespaces like the above code snippet does would clobber the semantics of a mixed-namespace document.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to build the whole document up in code and then write a general purpose method to apply one namespace to all elements. That's likely to be awkward to get right, but certainly *possible*.

Basically `new XElement("Child")` is documented to create an element without a namespace - you're not going to be able to change that.

Another option is to extract out all your element names into variables (either local or static readonly, probably) and apply the namespace *there*:

```
private static readonly XNamespace AdventureWorksNs = "http://www....";
private static readonly XName RootName = AdventureWorksNs + "Root";
private static readonly XName ChildName = AdventureWorksNs + "Child";
```

then

```
XElement root = new XElement(RootName,
    new XElement(ChildName, "child content")
);
```

Comment: If its supposed to create an element without a namespace why is an empty namespaces added?

Comment: I've observed that in general XML APIs are very awkward in spite of everyone's best attempts, and widespread attempts at wrapping them only result in API Babel.

Comment: See my answer for why the empty `xmlns` declaration is added.

Comment: The problem with your option is that I would like the Child elements to have no namespaces. Is there any way to do that?